# How to Combine Text Embeddings and Discrete/Categorical Data for NLP Classification

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, text-classification, embedding

I'm using 512-dimensional text embeddings for NLP text classification. I'd like to incorporate additional discrete and one-hot encoded categorical data.

I considered appending these to my text embeddings, expanding the vector's dimensionality (e.g., to 520 dimensions for 8 additional features). Is there a better way to do this?

Looking for methods to combine these data types effectively. Any potential issues with the append approach?

I am using sentence-transformers library for retrieving the embeddings and sklears's SVC model for classification.